# Date issue in @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, rest, date

I have a very trivial issue, and its taking a lot of my time.

I have a Spring Rest Service, which accepts a model object in @RequestBody.  What I am passing in the model object is date in format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'. 
The issue is when I am passing date i.e 2016-01-05T18:30:00.000Z from the html to the rest controller, it gets converted into 2016-01-04T18:30:00.000Z.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/clearance")
 public ResponseEntity<?> saveClearance(@RequestBody ClearanceModel record   ) { 
.....
....
 }
```

where ClearanceModel  is :

```
  public class ClearanceModel  {
  private String date;

  public String getDate() {
    return date;
   }

   public void setDate(String date) {
   this.date = date;
  }
}
```

FYI: this issue does not occur for EST, but occurs for IST.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where does this conversion happen? I see only a String parameter here. Is it converted in the frontend?

Comment: @SimoneZandara : I am not doing any explicit conversions, its done internally i believe by Jackson.

Comment: Jackson will not convert String data coming from the server implicitely. your model accept a String so if you pass a String "2016-01-05T18:30:00.000Z" that is what you will receive. Can you show the output of your request in raw format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be time zone issue. Changing the datatype to TIMESTAMP fixed it, While earlier it was of type DATE.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson provides a way to specify a custom serializer to entities. So you have to

- implement a custom serializer (eg. ClearanceModelSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ClearanceModel> )
- annotate your ClearanceModel with @JsonSerializer(using = ClearanceModelSerializer.class)

See more here: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Comment: The issue turned out to be time zone issue. Changing the time to timestamp fixed it, While earlier it was of type date.